# Add Bean and Interceptor to the context of an application from an external jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a web application with the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
class CustomMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleChangeInterceptor());
    }   
}
```

I want to add a dependency of a jar on the application, add another bean and another interceptor to the context.In another project I have another WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class but it does not run:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
class OtherCustomMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public OtherBean otherBean() {
        return new OtherBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CustomInterceptor());
    }   
}
```

If I try to inject the OtherBean into a class of the application web does not exist in context:

```
@Inject
private OtherBean otherBean;
```

And the CustomInterceptor does not run. How can I add beans and interceptors to an application from an external module?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add proper `@Include` annotation to your MVC Configuration.

```
@Include(OtherCustomMvcConfiguration.class)    
class CustomMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

Comment: I do not want to modify my CustomMvcConfiguration, I want to add the beans to the context only with include the dependency in the pom.xml file

Comment: Then, you need to add `@ComponentScan` annotation somewhere in your project and specify package/classname of `OtherCustomMvcConfiguration` class